# Firebase JS API: How to avoid `off()` getting executed before `on()` is called/finished executing?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In the following code, `off()` gets executed before `on()`. This happens because

> The DataSnapshot passed to the callback will be for the location at which on() was called. **It won't trigger until the entire contents has been synchronized.**

as mentioned in the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on

```
quotesRef.orderByChild('index').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapShot) {
        vm.allQuotes.push({
            key: childSnapShot.key,
            quoteTxt: childSnapShot.val().quote
        })
    })
})

quotesRef.off('value')
```

How to structure the above code, so that `off()` gets called only when content has fully synchronized or when `on` has actually been called.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you wan't to call off() straight after? If you [scroll down a bit in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) you find once(): _"This is equivalent to calling on(), and then calling off() inside the callback function."_

Comment: `once` is mostly for something that will not change often which is not the case with my code. Can you propose something that `off`is called only after `on` has finished. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call `off` after the data has been read from the database, move it into the callback:

```
quotesRef.orderByChild('index').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapShot) {
        vm.allQuotes.push({
            key: childSnapShot.key,
            quoteTxt: childSnapShot.val().quote
        })
    })
    quotesRef.off('value')
})
```

But as André commented, this is the exact equivalent of using `once()`:

```
quotesRef.orderByChild('index').once('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapShot) {
        vm.allQuotes.push({
            key: childSnapShot.key,
            quoteTxt: childSnapShot.val().quote
        })
    })
})
```